# Vk API PHP:Как получить фото от пользователя?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, php7

Ну тоесть, мне нужно, если пользователь отправить фото, то бот его скачает, и сохранит, как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте следующие методы:

messages.getConversations - С параметром filter= unread - получите список диалогов с непрочитанными сообщениями. В результате этого запроса получаете и парсите JSOn. Вам необходим этот параметр "conversation": {"id": 144429723. Это ID диалога с непрочитанными сообщениями. 
Добавляете все ID в список или массив с которым вы будете работать в дальнейшем.

Ссылка на метод https://vk.com/dev/messages.getConversations

Для каждого из ID из списка вызываете метод messages.getHistory c параметром peer_id=2000000000 + id из списка с id диалогов

ссылка на метод https://vk.com/dev/messages.getHistory

В результате запроса вы получите JSON который содержит историю сообщений в данном диалоге.
В данном JSON вы парсите все массивы "attachments". Нас интересуют все массивы в котором поле "type": "photo". 
В массиве "attachments" есть вложенный объект "photo": { в котором есть массив "sizes": [] который хранит объекты описывающие возможные размеры фотографий и ссылки на них.

Пример :
"sizes": [{

"type": "s",

"url": "https://sun1-84.u...0be/oIhpqkn1jCo.jpg",
"width": 75,

"height": 42

}

Определяетесь с нужным вам размером фотографии. По ссылке из поля "url" вы можете скачать фотографию.

Comment: А не проще ли callback/longpoll использовать для получения сообщения?